# Why is "crime story" more correct than "criminal story"?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, word-difference, attributive-nouns

*Criminal* is an adjective and *story* is a noun. Why is "crime story" used instead of "criminal story"? While both *crime* and *story* are nouns. What's this latter combination?

Is "criminal story" even correct?

Comment: The complex answers below are interesting, however, I would digress and point out the it's simply easier to say "crime story" since it's only 2 syllables.  Word shortening and phrase shortening are a fact of life. I contend that even if the common phrase were to be "criminal story" that, over time, it would probably become "crime story". The easier a phrase rolls off the tongue, the more likely it is to stick in culture.

Comment: @Michael.M Thanks. I see what you're saying, But I thought there would be some societies that protect rules of the language and prevent unfounded changes. Such as [Académie française](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acad%C3%A9mie_fran%C3%A7aise) which is for french.

Comment: I don't believe you'll find any such dictatorship in English cultures. Even the Oxford English Dictionary, which touts itself as "The definitive record of the English language" acknowledges new and un-traditional terms such as ["lol"](http://www.oed.com/search?searchType=dictionary&q=lol&_searchBtn=Search).  Actually English is described as a [mongrel](http://genius.com/Merriam-webster-weird-plurals-annotated) language because it lacks such formal protections, but instead borrows, to it's own pleasure, from everywhere else and is very adaptive in that way.

Answer (score 40):

"**Criminal**" means "against the law", like "*criminal behaviour*", "*criminal organisation*", "*criminal enterprise*", and so on.

The story is **not against the law**, the story is *about* a **crime**, so it's a *crime story*, not a criminal story.

---

Compare the difference in meaning between "a wooden shed" and "a wood shed".  The former is a shed made of wood, the latter is a shed where wood is kept.

Comment: Or a *love story* as opposed to a *loving story*.

Comment: *Crime law*, or *Criminal law*?

Comment: @brian_o - no one said English makes sense :D

Comment: Logic and grammar will only get you so far. In many cases, you cannot formulate a rule, but I fear this answer does. The following is incorrect:

The trial is **not against the law**, the trial is *about* a **crime**, so it's a *crime trial*, not a criminal trial.

Comment: @brian_o, When you say, "*In many cases, you cannot formulate a rule, but I fear this answer does.*", do you mean "this answer **tries**"?  I didn't really mean to pretend I know the rule, nor that I think there needs to be a rule.

Comment: @VictorBazarov My second sentence is not very well written. Please disregard it. My first and third sentences stand.

Comment: I wonder if we favor compound nouns more today than English speakers did in the past. Perhaps if we were just now organizing a court system to try people whom the government accuses of broking laws, and another in which private individuals can bring lawsuits, we might call them "crime court" and "lawsuit court" rather than "criminal court" and "civil court." In any case, many of these examples are combinations of words that have much more specific meanings than you can get by combining the meanings of the individual words.

Comment: @brian_o, noone said lawyers were good with English. And besides, all lawyers are crooked so in a way it is *criminal law*.

Comment: Are we talking about *a* crime?  Or just crime?  Most stories about criminals are likely to feature more than one crime.

Comment: @brian_o you could make the argument that criminal law is about criminals (noun), then it works.

Comment: @Jake You could make that argument, but would it help you understand why we say "crime story" instead of "criminal story"?

Comment: @brian_o Possibly yes. Because then, the decision between the usage of "crime story" and "criminal story" is only incorrect by common usage and not by a "rule", since the "rule" being discussed here is "noun as adjective vs. adjective". This is especially the case since criminal is both an adjective and a noun, while crime is only a noun.

Comment: @Jake Do you say that if the rule would have dominated, the phrase would be "_criminal story_" (as _adjective+noun_). [Was my grammar in this comment correct? lol]

Answer (score 16):

A crime story is a story about a crime.

A criminal story would be a story about a criminal.

Typically speaking, books written in this genre tend to be centered around the crime.  They will sometimes get into the criminal's life, but they equally get into the lives of other characters, especially the crime solver.

If one were to write a book and label it as a "criminal story," it would be a story about a criminal, or criminals in general.  It might cover life as a criminal, with all the trust challenges that come with that life.  It may include crimes, but the individual crimes would be less important than the life of the criminal.

I am unaware of any story that sells itself as a "criminal story," but if one existed, that is what I would expect to see, as a native English speaker trying to make sense of a pair of words.

Comment: The meaning of "criminal story" you have in mind (which I've never heard before, by the way) is another compound noun, much like "crime story", because you made it a story about "a criminal" (noun). I think the OP expected the first word to be an adjective rather than a noun.

Comment: I'd be happy to know if this interpretation of _Criminal story_ is your personal viewpoint or would be the same for other native English speakers? By the way, as @DavidK said, I assumed the _criminal_ to be an adjective.

Comment: @flower I tried to point out that it was my own viewpoint on what an English speaker would do if presented with those two words put next to each other.  I don't know if it helped to present my viewpoint, or hurt.  Sometimes you just want to hear "you should have said X," and sometimes you need to hear "you should have said X.  If you said Y, here's what I would have thought you said."  Actually, probably the most defining characteristic of a "criminal story" would be that it isn't just a "crime story."  English speakers may use modified constructions to try to distinguish their work...

Comment: ... so the mere use of an unusual construction usually begs for further clarification.  It might be, as I viewed it, "Oh no, this isn't a crime story.  This is a criminal story.  It really tries to get into the mind of the criminal." or it might be "Oh no, this isn't a crime story. This is a criminal story.  We only see the crime from the criminal's perspective."  Or, if you treat the word as an adjective, it might be as simple as "This story was so bad, and did so much damage to the genre with its horrible prortrayals that it's positively *criminal.*"

Comment: @CortAmmon: I would think the distinction between crime story and criminal story would depend upon whether it focused upon aspects of the criminal's life *outside of the crimes in which he was involved*.

Answer (score 11):

*Crime story* is a [compound noun](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/nouns/compound-noun.html) made of two base nouns. I think you were expecting an adjective-noun pair, but that's not how we express this idea in English.

Similar constructions from the linked source include "post office" and "fish tank".

*"Criminal story"* is not an immediately meaningful combination. We just don't use it that way, but sometimes we use similarly constructed phrases. A ***criminal trial*** is a *trial* about a *crime*, not a *trial* conducted in an *illegal manner*. Why can we say *"criminal trial"* and not *"criminal story"*? Unclear, but it may be because of the word *"story"*. When naming genres, we seem to prefer compound nouns: *"adventure story"*, *"romance story"*, etc.

Comment: @DavidK Yes, but in "criminal sanction", the word "criminal" actually is an adjective modifying the noun "sanction": but it **does not** describe a sanction that's so bad, it's criminal.

Comment: If English language learners ask: "criminal story" or "crime story", I can tell them which phrase is actually used. I can also tell them that one is an adjective-noun pair while the other is a compound noun. What I *cannot do* is explain why one "makes sense" while the other does not.

Comment: OK, I was being a bit facetious with the "so bad, it's criminal." Nobody actually used that phrase (I think it's slang, actually) when naming legal concepts. Notice, though, how many of these uses of "criminal" as an adjective come from the actual practice of law. I don't think there's much use for works of popular fiction in that context.

Comment: Please do remove "criminal trespass" because it completely weakens your statements.

Comment: @ErikE How does it weaken my point? Contrast "criminal trespass" and "criminal trial". Both are adjective-noun pairs, but the adjective "criminal" means something different. In the first, "criminal" means "illegal", whereas in the second, "criminal" means "crime-focused". My point is that the meaning is inconsistent; in order to use the proper phrase, *you just have to know.* You can't use logic to arrive at the proper usage.

Comment: I've got a bit confused when saw _adjective-noun_ could be a branch of _compound nouns_ in the link you've given. While you used them something opposite in [your 2nd comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/72060/why-is-crime-story-more-correct-than-criminal-story#comment138096_72092).

Comment: So when you say, "_Criminal story_ is not a valid combination"; Do you believe that the interpretation which says "[A criminal story would be a story about a criminal.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/72068/19092)" isn't a stable one?

Comment: Another vague point for me is if the _criminal story_  compound could present the evil of a story. A story which in its heart is evil (and maybe hurtful) like a common criminal act.

Comment: Finally, I think of _crime story_ as two nouns which one is modifying another and that's the meaning of a _Genitive Case_. Why is the combination of "**the story of a crime**" not the chosen one, which preserves the structure of the _genitive case_?

Comment: And note that we refer to it as a "criminal trial" to distinguish it from a "civil trial", not because it's about a criminal.

Comment: @flower 1of4: Sorry for the confusion. I was calling a regular adjective which modifies a regular noun an "adjective-noun" pair. Example: red car. I forgot that the explanation of compound nouns included some examples of adjective-noun constructs: blackboard. It's not just any board that's black, that phrase specifically means chalkboard.

Comment: @flower 2of4: As Cort Ammon said, "criminal story" is an unusual construction that demands further explanation. I agree that a native English speaker might initially guess that it is a story about a criminal.

Comment: @flower 3of4: I see what you're saying, but I think if you want to describe an evil story trying to use criminal might not work very well. I think because "criminal" is closer associated with legality rather than evil. (Tax fraud is criminal but not chillingly evil.)

Comment: @flower 4of4: "The story of a crime" could work just as well [and possibly better] in many situations. "A crime story" is shorter but has pretty much the same meaning. "Crime story" is possibly better suited to describe a given story's genre.

Answer (score 3):

While writing a comment, I figured I should probably write it as an answer.

As brian_o said in his answer, *crime story* is a compound noun. Generally a compound noun is used to describe a more specific version of something. A post office is an office for post, a wood shed is a shed for wood, a crime story is a story about crime.

The main issue is that the word [*criminal*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/criminal) has an adjective usage and a noun usage. So logically *criminal story* is just as correct as *crime story*. In usage, crime story is considered "correct" as it is the common usage.

Comment: Beside compound nouns which stand for a specific type of something (as you pointed); Aren't other combinations of two _nouns_ just "genitive cases"? If yes, as I mentioned in comments for `brian_o`; Shouldn't it be "_noun + of + noun_"? In the viewpoint of the language rules. (Or maybe rules of the language)

Comment: It could be constructed with of by saying "the story of a crime", but to a native speaker "story about a crime" sounds better.

Comment: I wouldn't encourage you to think of all compound nouns as just "genitive." Sometimes that mental model might work, but I think it fails in other cases. For instance, a *rain garden* isn't really a *garden of rain*.

Comment: @brian_o I excepted compound nouns in the first comment as a combination which identifies a certain version of something. Doesn't _a rain of garden_ identify a special garden, even if it's fictional?